# how socket.io get downloaded from my server even I didn't assign any router for it

Tags: socket.io

how nodejs handle /socket/socket.io.js/ request even I don't assigned any router for it

this is script tag in html

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and this is my simple nodejs server

```
var express = require('express');
  var path = require('path');
  var app = express();
  var server = require('http').Server(app);
  var io = require('socket.io')(server);
  var port = 8080;

  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

  server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log("Listening on port " + port);
  });
```

it should get this error : 404 page not found
but it correctly load it

Comment: If your browser can read this page it can read the JavaScript. Unclear what you're asking,

Answer (score 1):

It's the default behaviour of socket.io server .

take a look here: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/

it's called "serveClient" and it's set to true as default .

Comment: you mean that socket automatically add a middle-ware to server

Comment: yup , exactly like this .